# c# asynchronous server reply

Tags: c#, sockets

First off I do apologize in case that a question like this exists, I searched on google and read through Questions that may have my answer but couldn't find it.
I have the following server code:

```
private void StartServer()
{
    try
    {
        sSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, (SocketOptionName)27, 0);
        sSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6666));
        sSocket.Listen(0);
        sSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Server", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        cSocket = sSocket.EndAccept(ar);
        buffer = new byte[cSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        cSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
        sSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Server", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int received = cSocket.EndReceive(ar);

        if(received == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Array.Resize(ref buffer, received);
        text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        DisplayText(text);
        cSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Server", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

private void DisplayText(string text)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
    {
        textBox.Text += ">> " + text + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
    }));
}
```

And the following client code:

```
private void connect()
{
    try
    {
        cSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        cSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, (SocketOptionName)27, 0);
        cSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 6666), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Registracija", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        cSocket.EndConnect(ar);
        buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sendstuff");
        cSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), null);
    }
    catch (SocketException) { }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Registracija", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

private void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    cSocket.EndSend(ar);
}
```

I know that I'm using a local ip on a external ip capable socket. I just deleted some non important stuff and put the local ip to hide the external one. So I connect the client to the server, no problem there, everything works great, and I can send data to the server without problems but I can't figure out/find anywhere how to make the server reply something to the client. For an example lets say I send a string to the server saying "I'm a string". Now the server does something with that string, let's say cuts off "I'm" and now it needs to send back to the client the remainder of that which is "a string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `cSocket.BeginSend` right at where you call `DisplayText`? Obviously to be able to use `BeginSend`, you would need to put the text into a buffer. There are various ways of doing it efficiently, but it is out of this answer's scope.

**But** if you are expecting some kind of structured data such as strings separated by newline characters, then you are better off using `StreamReader.ReadLine`. If the structure is more complicated, then you would need to do the parsing yourself from the buffer. So you need to consume a character from the buffer, see if you have enough data, if not keep consuming until buffer is empty. When buffer is empty, you need to fill it again by calling `BeginReceive`. When you have enough data to process, send back a response using either `BeginSend` or one of stream write functions.

Network programming is no easy task, you should check out some example server/client code from the internet and understand them throughly. Last but not least, I suggest you to use await/async syntactic sugars.

Comment: Strings being sent are pretty simple so a buffer works fine in my case. The thing is if I BeginSend where i call display text how will the client recieve it since there are no ReceiveCallbacks and such?

Comment: Obviously you need to use `BeginReceive` and register your callback in the client right before you send your data, i.e. in `ConnectCallback` function. The thing is, multiple "sends" can be received in a single "receive" callback on the other side and vice versa. Because you are working with streams, so be careful with that. That's why you need a separator character / structured data if you want to process data multiple times, e.g. remove "I'm" from multiple sentences.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to strings sent back and forth using streams, I use a `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` like so:

**Server side**

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(theStream))
{
    string message = reader.ReadLine();

    // Or in an async method
    string message = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

**Client side**

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(theStream))
{
    writer.WriteLine(theMessage);

    // Or in an async method
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(theMessage);
}
```

**Note:** Since you are using TCP, you can get a `NetworkStream` from a TCP socket using `new NetworkStream(theSocket)`.